# C# VS.NET 2008 Changing settings per configuration

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, appsettings

Is there a way to have different application settings per each build configuration?

I would like to be able to batch build a few configurations with different settings, instead of having to change the settings and build, rinse repeat.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96340/best-approach-for-configuring-multiple-net-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about the appsettings architecture (I've never really used it), but you can define different values for constants using a bit of MSBuild magic.

Create two .cs files, Constants1.cs and Constants2.cs (or name them after your configurations).

In each file, define a class called Constants (or whatever) -- but do it as if each file were the only definition (ie. use the same class name).  Typically, this should just define `public static readonly` fields -- do **not** use `const`, as that can get you into trouble with partial builds.

Now Unload your project file and Edit it.  Find the entries that look like this:

```
    <Compile Include="Constants1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Constants2.cs" />
```

and change them like so:

```
    <Compile Include="Constants1.cs" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" />
    <Compile Include="Constants2.cs" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" />
```

Finally Save and Reload your project.  Now only one of the files will actually be built at a time, depending on your build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a prebuild or postbuild task to the proj, you have access to the ConfigurationName from there. Would be fairly easy to do something like "copy Web.config.debug Web.config"

Answer (score 0):

Besides all these, MS promised to add this feature in VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean under 'application settings' ? Project's property for each configuration such as Debug or Release? Or defirent app.conf file for each of them?

If first, you can create a number of configurations with suitable settings and use Batch Build to build them by turn.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/169az28z.aspx

or as Google Ninja said, use pre-build task:
del Web.config app.config
copy Web.config.Debug Web.config
(create a number of configuration files before it)